# Simulate a two-dimensional random walk in a grid in R and plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, random-walk, geom-tile

I was looking for a simple code that could simulate a two-dimensional random walk in a grid (using `R`), and then plot the data using `ggplot`.

In particular, I was interested to a random walk from few position (5 points) in a 2D grid to the center of the square grid. It is just for visualisation purposes.

And my idea was then to plot the results with `ggplot` on a discrete grid (as the one simulated), may be using the function `geom_tile`.

Do you have any suggestion for a pre-existing code that I could easily manipulate?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? Can you give an example of what it would look like?

Comment: Something similar to this http://www.econometricsbysimulation.com/2012/08/a-visual-exploration-of-two-dimensional.html, but in a grid.

Comment: Why geom_tile()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### EDIT ----

After chatting with OP I've revised the code to include a step probability. This may result in the walk being stationary much more frequently. In higher dimensions, you will need to scale your `prob` factor lower in order to compensate for more options.

finally, my function does not account for an absolute distance, it only considers points on the grid that are within a certain step size in all dimensions. For example, hypothetically, at position `c(0,0)` you could go to `c(1,1)` with this function. But I guess this is relative to the grid's connectiveness.

If the OP wants to only consider nodes that are within 1 (by distance) of the current position, then use the following version of `move_step()`

```r
move_step <- function(cur_pos, grid, prob = 0.04, size = 1){
  opts <- grid %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(across(.fns = ~(.x-.env$cur_pos[[cur_column()]])^2,
                  .names = '{.col}_square_diff')) %>%
    filter(sqrt(sum(c_across(ends_with("_square_diff"))))<=.env$size) %>%
    select(-ends_with("_square_diff")) %>%
    left_join(y = mutate(cur_pos, current = TRUE), by = names(grid)) 
  new_pos <- opts %>%
    mutate(weight = case_when(current ~ 1-(prob*(n()-1)), #calculate chance to move, 
                              TRUE ~ prob),               #in higher dimensions, we may have more places to move
           weight = if_else(weight<0, 0, weight)) %>%    #thus depending on prob, we may always move.
    sample_n(size = 1, weight = weight) %>%
    select(-weight, -current)
  new_pos
}
```

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

move_step <- function(cur_pos, grid, prob = 0.04, size = 1){
  opts <- grid %>%
    filter(across(.fns =  ~ between(.x, .env$cur_pos[[cur_column()]]-.env$size, .env$cur_pos[[cur_column()]]+.env$size))) %>%
    left_join(y = mutate(cur_pos, current = TRUE), by = names(grid)) 
  new_pos <- opts %>%
    mutate(weight = case_when(current ~ 1-(prob*(n()-1)), #calculate chance to move, 
                              TRUE ~ prob),               #in higher dimensions, we may have more places to move
           weight = if_else(weight<0, 0, weight)) %>%    #thus depending on prob, we may always move.
    sample_n(size = 1, weight = weight) %>%
    select(-weight, -current)
  new_pos
}

sim_walk <- function(cur_pos, grid, grid_prob = 0.04, steps = 50, size = 1){
  iterations <- cur_pos
  for(i in seq_len(steps)){
    cur_pos <- move_step(cur_pos, grid, prob = grid_prob, size = size)
    iterations <- bind_rows(iterations, cur_pos)
  }
  iterations$i <- 1:nrow(iterations)
  iterations
}

origin <- data.frame(x = 0, y =0)
small_grid <- expand.grid(x = -1:1, y = -1:1)
small_walk <- sim_walk(cur_pos = origin,
                       grid = small_grid)

ggplot(small_walk, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  transition_reveal(i) +
  labs(title = "Step {frame_along}") +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

```r
large_grid <- expand.grid(x = -10:10, y = -10:10)
large_walk <- sim_walk(cur_pos = origin,
                       grid = large_grid,
                       steps = 100)

ggplot(large_walk, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  transition_reveal(i)  +
  labs(title = "Step {frame_along}") +
  xlim(c(-10,10)) + ylim(c(-10,10))+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

```r
large_walk %>% 
  count(x, y) %>%
  right_join(y = expand.grid(x = -10:10, y = -10:10), by = c("x","y")) %>%
  mutate(n = if_else(is.na(n), 0L, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

```r
multi_dim_walk <- sim_walk(cur_pos = data.frame(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0),
                           grid =  expand.grid(x = -20:20, y = -20:20, z = -20:20),
                           steps = 100, size = 2)

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(
  ggplot(multi_dim_walk, aes(x, y)) + geom_path(),
  ggplot(multi_dim_walk, aes(x, z)) + geom_path(),
  ggplot(multi_dim_walk, aes(y, z)) + geom_path())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is very impressive and interesting. I was wandering whether you think that it might be possible to include a move step probability..that its, for instance every step has a probability of 4% to occur for time interval = 1. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: maybe, but I think it would be helpful if you could be more specific in your post about what you may expect in the simulation. What are the constraints, can a single step take you anywhere in the grid (i.e. step size is not important). Or do you want each grid position to have a different probability depending on time or distance from the current position. These details can change the code drastically

Comment: I reply to your questions here first and then I will update my post. The constraints are: step size = 1, and such step move occur with a given probability px. Steps occur over discrete time intervals. Each grid position has the same probability to move, but given that I set step size of 1, then for each discrete time point there will be only one step, assuming that occurs (dependent on px). Is it a bit clearer? Sorry if it is not and I will try again.

Comment: Okay, so if there are 3 positions we could move to, and `px = 0.04` (4%), then there is a 12% chance to move and a 88% change it stays on the current position?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For simplicity, I assume that there are 4 neighbouring positions, except at the edges or corner of the grid where there are 3 and 2 positions available, respectively.

Comment: Unrelated to what you are currently discussing, but may I recommend you use `+ coord_fixed(1)` in order to set the ggplot axes to the same scale. What an excellent solution though!

Comment: re-rendering the reprex now.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small example with a `for` loop. From here, you can simply adjust how `X_t` and `Y_t` are defined:

```
Xt = 0; Yt = 0
for (i in 2:1000)
{
  Xt[i] = Xt[i-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
  Yt[i] = Yt[i-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
}
df <- data.frame(x = Xt, y = Yt)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_path() + theme_classic() + coord_fixed(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `Reduce` + `replicate` + `plot` for 2D random walk process

```
set.seed(0)
plot(
  setNames(
    data.frame(replicate(
      2,
      Reduce(`+`, rnorm(99), init = 0, accumulate = TRUE)
    )),
    c("X", "Y")
  ),
  type = "o"
)
```

[image]